# Proving integral equalities with invariant measures

Tags: measure-theory

I try to show the following 2 results:

$(X,\mu)$ is a measure space. $f$ and $g$ are 2 functions sufficiently integrable/measurable for the expressions to make sense. We assume that $\mu(f^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)$ on the $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. Then:

$\int_Xgofd\mu=\int_Xgd\mu$ and $\int_X|gof|²d\mu=\int_X|g|^2d\mu$

My approach is to prove the first equality on indicator functions first, then extend by linearity to simple functions and then to non-negative $L^1$ functions, since they are measurable and any non-negative measurable function can be expressed as pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of simple functions (the monotone convergence theorem being used to swap integral and limit). Is that the right approach?

Now, I'd like to do the same for the second equality but the |.| and the 2-power destroy the linearity argument. How to go around this?

Comment: This is the right approach. The second equality is a straightforward application of the first one, with $\tilde{g} = |g|^2$.

Comment: Right, I guess that was obvious after all. This means that we may extend the equality to $L^p$ functions?